# How to delete duplicate (repetitive) records, rows from table without id

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have studied on it and the most practical way I found was to create a procedure. The procedure
adds an id, delete duplicate rows, and finally adds an id column to newly formed table. I wonder, there must be an easier way. Here's the code, it works...

--my table

```
create table dublicateTable
(
name varchar(30)
)
```

--duplicatedly inserted rows

```
insert into dublicateTable values('Kerem')
insert into dublicateTable values('Taner')
insert into dublicateTable values('Mehmet')
insert into dublicateTable values('Serhat')
```

--first situation

```
select * from dublicateTable


name
-----
Kerem
Kerem
Kerem
Taner
Taner
Mehmet
Mehmet
Mehmet
Mehmet
Serhat
Serhat
Serhat
```

--dynamicaly formed sql code procedure

```
USE [myDataBase]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
create procedure [dbo].[usp_delete_duplicate]
as
declare 
@add_id_text nvarchar(50),
@delete_id_text nvarchar(50),
@command_text nvarchar(100)
begin
set @add_id_text='alter table dbo.dublicateTable add id int identity(1,1)'
set @command_text='delete from dbo.dublicateTable where id not in(select min(id) from dbo.dublicateTable group by name)'
set @delete_id_text='alter table dbo.dublicateTable drop column id'
exec sp_executesql @add_id_text
exec sp_executesql @command_text
exec sp_executesql @delete_id_text
exec sp_executesql @add_id_text
end
```

--final situation.it works..

```
exec usp_delete_duplicate


select id,name from dublicateTable


id      name
---     ----
 1      Kerem
 2      Taner
 3      Mehmet
 4      Serhat
```

Comment: yes but different point of view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A CTE can make it much simpler to write.

```
;with cte as (
    select
        name,
        row_number() over (partition by name order by name) row
    from
        dublicateTable
)
delete from cte where row > 1
```

Comment: It's not necessary to include the 'name' field in the cte, since it's not used directly in the query.